# Python sorted object

Tags: python, django

I have query that is sorted via python however I would like to exclude the brands with the distance greater than 100km this is what I wrote, however it always gets distance that is beyond 100km

```
 return sorted(
    root.brands.filter(status=True, region_id=area),
            key=lambda qs: (qs.distance(**kwargs) <= 100, qs.distance(**kwargs) < 100 if 
   qs.distance(**kwargs) > 0 else [])
 )
```

is there any way to do this? thanks

Comment: Well, you're not *excluding* by distance, you're just sorting by distance.

Comment: @deceze the code (presumably) intends to use `root.brands.filter` (whatever that is) to (presumably) grab only the nearby brands, and then sort them (by some unspecified means). Of course, that would require using some parameter or other of `root.brands.filter` to exclude based on distance, not a parameter of `sorted`.

Comment: Denmg, share your model

Comment: Distance is based on the store long lat and user lo g lat

Comment: Distance is a function between store and user long lat,  I had to use sorted, to sort them I also want to remove store thats beyond 100km, is there a condition to filter this using sort?